# NS2: Packets won't forward data

Tags: tcl, packet, ns2

I modified the M-DART tcl file in NS2 to run multi-channels instead of single channel. I already assigned the sending and receiving nodes but the packets did not forwarded to the destination node. The only action is send, receive and dropping packets. This is my modified script:

```
###########################################
#      Define Option
###########################################
set val(chan)       Channel/WirelessChannel; #channel type
set val(ant)        Antenna/OmniAntenna;     #antenna type
set val(propagation)    Shado;                   #propagation model
set val(netif)      Phy/WirelessPhy;      #network interface type
set val(ll)     LL;           #link layer type
set val(ifq)        Queue/DropTail;   #interface queue type
set val(ifqlen) 50;                      #max packet in ifq
set val(mac)        Mac/802_11;              #MAC type
set val(rp)     MDART;                   #routing protocol
set val(n)      10  ;                    #node number
set val(density)    4096;                    #node density [node/km^2]
set val(end)        206.0;                   #simulation time [s]
set val(dataStart)  100.0;                   #data start time [s]
set val(dataStop)   [expr $val(end) - 6.0];  #data stop time [s]
set val(seed)       1;                       #general pseudo-random sequence generator
set val(macFailed)  true;                    #ATR protocol: ns2 MAC failed callback
set val(etxMetric)  true;                    #ATR protocol: ETX route metric
set val(throughput) 5.40;                    #CBR rate (<= 5.4Mb/s)

#########################################
#       Channel Model
#########################################
#Setting antenna at center of node, 1.5 meters above it
Antenna/OmniAntenna set X_ 0
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Y_ 0
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Z_ 1.2
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Gt_ 1.0     ;#transmitter gain
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Gr_ 1.0     ;#receiver gain
Phy/WirelessPhy set L_ 1.0          ;#system loss factor
if {$val(propagation) == "TwoRay"} {
        set val(prop) Propagation/TwoRayGround
        set prop [new $val(prop)]
        Phy/WirelessPhy set CPThresh_ 10.0  ;#capt. thresh. in Watt
        Phy/WirelessPhy set CSThresh_ 1.559e-11 ;#carr. sens. thresh.
        Phy/WirelessPhy set RXThresh_ 3.652e-10 ;#receive signal thresh
        Phy/WirelessPhy set freq_ 2.4e9 ;#chan. freq. (Hz)
        Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 0.28        ;#trans. signal power (Watt)
}
if {$val(propagation) == "Shado"} {
        set val(prop) Propagation/Shadowing
        set prop [new $val(prop)]
        $prop set pathlossExp_ 3.8  ;#path loss exponent
        $prop set std_db_ 2.0       ;#shadowing deviation (dB)
        $prop set seed_ 1       ;#RNG seed
        $prop set dist0_ 1.0        ;#ref. distance (m)
        $prop set CPThresh_ 10.0    ;#capt. thresh (Watt)
        $prop set RXThresh_ 2.37e-13    ;#rec. sign. thresh
        $prop set CSThresh_ [expr 2.37e-13 * 0.0427] ;#carr. sens. thresh
        $prop set freq_ 2.4e9       ;#chann. freq (Hz)
        Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 0.28
}

#####################################################
#       Topology Definition
#####################################################
#Scenario creation according to chosen node density
set val(dim) [expr $val(n) / $val(density)]
set val(x) [expr [expr sqrt($val(dim))] * 1000]
set val(y) [expr [expr sqrt($val(dim))] * 1000]

####################################################
#       Pseudo-random sequence generator
####################################################

#General pseudo-random sequence geneator
set genSeed [new RNG]
$genSeed seed $val(seed)
set randomSeed [new RandomVariable/Uniform]
$randomSeed use-rng $genSeed
$randomSeed set min_ 1.0
$randomSeed set max_ 100.0

#Mobility model: x node position [m]
set genNodeX [new RNG]
$genNodeX seed [expr [$randomSeed value]]
set randomNodeX [new RandomVariable/Uniform]
$randomNodeX use-rng $genNodeX
$randomNodeX set min_ 1.0
$randomNodeX set max_ [expr $val(x) - 1.0]

#Mobility model: Y node position [m]
set posNodeY [new RNG]
$posNodeY seed [expr [$randomSeed value]]
set randomNodeY [new RandomVariable/Uniform]
$randomNodeY use-rng $posNodeY
$randomNodeY set min_ 1.0
$randomNodeY set max_ [expr $val(y) - 1.0]

#Data pattern: node
set genNode [new RNG]
$genNode seed [expr [$randomSeed value]]
set randomNode [new RandomVariable/Uniform]
$randomNode use-rng $genNode
$randomNode set min_ 0
$randomNode set max_ [expr $val(n) - 1]

################################
#     General definition
################################
#Instantiate the simulator
set ns [new Simulator]

#Define topology
set topo [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)

#create GOD
create-god $val(n)

##############################
#   Trace file definition
##############################
;#create trace object for ns, nam, monitor and inspect
set tracefile [open ns.tr w] ;#Adding this
$ns trace-all $tracefile ;#adding this
;#new format for wireless traces
$ns use-newtrace
#set namTr [open nam.tr w]
#$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namTr $val(x) $val(y)
#set scenarioTr [open scenario.tr w]

#nam file creation
set namfile [open mdart.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $namfile
$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namfile $val(x) $val(y)
#set chan [new $val(chan)];

#create channel
set chan_1_ [new $val(chan)]
set chan_2_ [new $val(chan)]

$prop topography $topo

#Global node setting
$ns node-config  -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
         -llType $val(ll) \
         -macType $val(mac) \
         -ifqType $val(ifq) \
         -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
         -antType $val(ant) \
         -propInstance $prop \
         -phyType $val(netif) \
         -topoInstance $topo \
         -agentTrace ON \
         -routerTrace ON \
         -macTrace OFF \
         -movementTrace OFF \
         -channel $chan_1_ 

################################
#    Nodes definition
################################
;#  Create the specified number of nodes [$val(n)] and "attach" them to the channel.
#for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n) } {incr i} {
#   set node($i) [$ns node]
#   $node($i) random-motion 0        ; #disabled random motion
    #$ns initial_node_pos $n($i) 20 ;
#}  

################################
#    Node conode(figurationode(
################################
;#node initial coordinates
set node(0) [$ns node]
$node(0) random-motion 0
$node(0) set X_ 20.0
$node(0) set Y_ 65.0
$node(0) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(0) 20

set node(1) [$ns node]
$node(1) random-motion 0
$node(1) set X_ 50.0
$node(1) set Y_ 10.0
$node(1) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(1) 20

set node(2) [$ns node]
$node(2) random-motion 0
$node(2) set X_ 0.0
$node(2) set Y_ 0.0
$node(2) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(2) 20

set node(3) [$ns node]
$node(3) random-motion 0
$node(3) set X_ 95.0
$node(3) set Y_ 35.0
$node(3) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(3) 20

set node(4) [$ns node]
$node(4) random-motion 0
$node(4) set X_ 8.0
$node(4) set Y_ 50.0
$node(4) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(4) 20

$ns node-config \
    -channel $chan_2_

set node(5) [$ns node]
$node(5) random-motion 0
$node(5) set X_ 150.0
$node(5) set Y_ 165.0
$node(5) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(5) 20

set node(6) [$ns node]
$node(6) random-motion 0
$node(6) set X_ 30.0
$node(6) set Y_ 70.0
$node(6) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(6) 20

set node(7) [$ns node]
$node(7) random-motion 0
$node(7) set X_ 65.0
$node(7) set Y_ 114.0
$node(7) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(7) 20

set node(8) [$ns node]
$node(8) random-motion 0
$node(8) set X_ 50.0
$node(8) set Y_ 165.0
$node(8) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(8) 20

set node(9) [$ns node]
$node(9) random-motion 0
$node(9) set X_ 180.0
$node(9) set Y_ 100.0
$node(9) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(9) 20 


###################################
#     Nodes placement
###################################
#parameters for trace Inspect
#puts $scenarioTr "# nodes: $val(n), max time: $val(end)"
#puts $scenarioTr "# nominal range: 250"
#for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n)} {incr i} { 
#   set X [expr [$randomNodeX value] ]
#   $node($i) set X_ $X
#   set Y [expr [$randomNodeY value] ]
#   $node($i) set Y_ $Y
#   $node($i) set Z_ 0.0
#   $ns initial_node_pos $node($i) 20
#   puts $scenarioTr "\$node_($i) set X_ $X"
#   puts $scenarioTr "\$node_($i) set Y_ $Y"
#   puts $scenarioTr "\$node_($i) set Z_ 0.0"
#}

###################################
# moving nodes
###################################
#$ns at 3.0 "$node(0) setdest 175.0 90.0 0.0"
#$ns at 3.0 "$node(6) setdest 52.0 12.0 0.0"

#############################
#    Data load
#############################

    set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
    $ns attach-agent $node(0) $udp0
    set null0 [new Agent/Null]
    $ns attach-agent $node(6) $null0
    $ns connect $udp0 $null0

    set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
    $cbr0 set packetSize_ 1000
    $cbr0 attach-agent $udp0
    $cbr0 set rate_ [expr $val(throughput) / [expr $val(n) * sqrt($val(n))]]Mb
    $ns at $val(dataStart) "$cbr0 start"
    $ns at $val(dataStop) "$cbr0 stop"

###############################
#   Routing model (for M-DART)
###############################
if {$val(rp) == "M-DART"} {
    Agent/ATR set macFailed_ $val(macFailed)
    Agent/ATR set etxMetric_ $val(etxMetric)
}

############################
#    Tracing
############################
;#Simulation time print
proc timeTrace { tracePause} {
    global ns
    set now [$ns now]
    $ns at [expr $now + $tracePause] "timeTrace $tracePause"
    puts "$now simulation seconds"
}

$ns at 10.0 "timeTrace 10.0"

if {$val(rp) == "MDART"} {
    for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n)} {incr i} {
        # printing the routing table
        $ns at [expr $val(end) - 1.0]  "[$node($i) agent 255] routingTablePrint"
        # printing the dht table
        $ns at [expr $val(end) - 0.5]  "[$node($i) agent 255] dhtTablePrint"
    }
}

#########################
#    Start and end
#########################
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n) } {incr i} {
        $ns at $val(end) "$node($i) reset";
}

$ns at $val(end) "fileTrace"
$ns at $val(end) "$ns halt"

proc fileTrace {} {
    #global ns tracefile namTr
    global ns tracefile scenarioTr
    $ns flush-trace
    close $tracefile ;#adding tis
    #close $scenarioTr
    #close $namTr
    #exec nam nam.tr &
}

$ns run
```

This one only produce sent and drop packets. While this one:

```
###########################################
#      Define Option
###########################################
set val(chan)       Channel/WirelessChannel; #channel type
set val(ant)        Antenna/OmniAntenna;     #antenna type
set val(propagation)    Shado;                   #propagation model
set val(netif)      Phy/WirelessPhy;      #network interface type
set val(ll)     LL;           #link layer type
set val(ifq)        Queue/DropTail;   #interface queue type
set val(ifqlen) 50;                      #max packet in ifq
set val(mac)        Mac/802_11;              #MAC type
set val(rp)     MDART;                   #routing protocol
set val(n)      16  ;                    #node number
set val(density)    4096;                    #node density [node/km^2]
set val(end)        206.0;                   #simulation time [s]
set val(dataStart)  100.0;                   #data start time [s]
set val(dataStop)   [expr $val(end) - 6.0];  #data stop time [s]
set val(seed)       1;                       #general pseudo-random sequence generator
set val(macFailed)  true;                    #ATR protocol: ns2 MAC failed callback
set val(etxMetric)  true;                    #ATR protocol: ETX route metric
set val(throughput) 5.40;                    #CBR rate (<= 5.4Mb/s)

#########################################
#       Channel Model
#########################################
#Setting antenna at center of node, 1.5 meters above it
Antenna/OmniAntenna set X_ 0
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Y_ 0
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Z_ 1.2
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Gt_ 1.0     ;#transmitter gain
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Gr_ 1.0     ;#receiver gain
Phy/WirelessPhy set L_ 1.0          ;#system loss factor
if {$val(propagation) == "TwoRay"} {
        set val(prop) Propagation/TwoRayGround
        set prop [new $val(prop)]
        Phy/WirelessPhy set CPThresh_ 10.0  ;#capt. thresh. in Watt
        Phy/WirelessPhy set CSThresh_ 1.559e-11 ;#carr. sens. thresh.
        Phy/WirelessPhy set RXThresh_ 3.652e-10 ;#receive signal thresh
        Phy/WirelessPhy set freq_ 2.4e9 ;#chan. freq. (Hz)
        Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 0.28        ;#trans. signal power (Watt)
}
if {$val(propagation) == "Shado"} {
        set val(prop) Propagation/Shadowing
        set prop [new $val(prop)]
        $prop set pathlossExp_ 3.8  ;#path loss exponent
        $prop set std_db_ 2.0       ;#shadowing deviation (dB)
        $prop set seed_ 1       ;#RNG seed
        $prop set dist0_ 1.0        ;#ref. distance (m)
        $prop set CPThresh_ 10.0    ;#capt. thresh (Watt)
        $prop set RXThresh_ 2.37e-13    ;#rec. sign. thresh
        $prop set CSThresh_ [expr 2.37e-13 * 0.0427] ;#carr. sens. thresh
        $prop set freq_ 2.4e9       ;#chann. freq (Hz)
        Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 0.28
}

#####################################################
#       Topology Definition
#####################################################
#Scenario creation according to chosen node density
set val(dim) [expr $val(n) / $val(density)]
set val(x) [expr [expr sqrt($val(dim))] * 1000]
set val(y) [expr [expr sqrt($val(dim))] * 1000]

####################################################
#       Pseudo-random sequence generator
####################################################

#General pseudo-random sequence geneator
set genSeed [new RNG]
$genSeed seed $val(seed)
set randomSeed [new RandomVariable/Uniform]
$randomSeed use-rng $genSeed
$randomSeed set min_ 1.0
$randomSeed set max_ 100.0

#Mobility model: x node position [m]
set genNodeX [new RNG]
$genNodeX seed [expr [$randomSeed value]]
set randomNodeX [new RandomVariable/Uniform]
$randomNodeX use-rng $genNodeX
$randomNodeX set min_ 1.0
$randomNodeX set max_ [expr $val(x) - 1.0]

#Mobility model: Y node position [m]
set posNodeY [new RNG]
$posNodeY seed [expr [$randomSeed value]]
set randomNodeY [new RandomVariable/Uniform]
$randomNodeY use-rng $posNodeY
$randomNodeY set min_ 1.0
$randomNodeY set max_ [expr $val(y) - 1.0]

#Data pattern: node
set genNode [new RNG]
$genNode seed [expr [$randomSeed value]]
set randomNode [new RandomVariable/Uniform]
$randomNode use-rng $genNode
$randomNode set min_ 0
$randomNode set max_ [expr $val(n) - 1]

################################
#     General definition
################################
#Instantiate the simulator
set ns [new Simulator]

#Define topology
set topo [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)

#create GOD
create-god $val(n)

##############################
#   Trace file definition
##############################
;#create trace object for ns, nam, monitor and inspect
set tracefile [open ns.tr w] ;#Adding this
$ns trace-all $tracefile ;#adding this
;#new format for wireless traces
$ns use-newtrace
set namTr [open nam.tr w]
$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namTr $val(x) $val(y)
set scenarioTr [open scenario.tr w]

#nam file creation
#set namfile [open mdart.nam w]
#$ns namtrace-all $namfile
#$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namfile $val(x) $val(y)
#set chan [new $val(chan)];

#create channel
set chan_1_ [new $val(chan)]
set chan_2_ [new $val(chan)]

$prop topography $topo

#Global node setting
$ns node-config  -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
         -llType $val(ll) \
         -macType $val(mac) \
         -ifqType $val(ifq) \
         -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
         -antType $val(ant) \
         -propInstance $prop \
         -phyType $val(netif) \
         -topoInstance $topo \
         -agentTrace ON \
         -routerTrace ON \
         -macTrace OFF \
         -movementTrace OFF \
         -channel $chan_1_

################################
#    Nodes definition
################################
;#  Create the specified number of nodes [$val(n)] and "attach" them to the channel.
#for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n) } {incr i} {
#   set node($i) [$ns node]
#   $node($i) random-motion 0        ; #disabled random motion
    #$ns initial_node_pos $n($i) 20 ;
#}  

################################
#    Node conode(figurationode(
################################
;#node initial coordinates
set node(0) [$ns node]
$node(0) random-motion 0
$node(0) set X_ 20.0
$node(0) set Y_ 65.0
$node(0) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(0) 20

set node(1) [$ns node]
$node(1) random-motion 0
$node(1) set X_ 50.0
$node(1) set Y_ 10.0
$node(1) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(1) 20

set node(2) [$ns node]
$node(2) random-motion 0
$node(2) set X_ 0.0
$node(2) set Y_ 0.0
$node(2) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(2) 20

set node(3) [$ns node]
$node(3) random-motion 0
$node(3) set X_ 95.0
$node(3) set Y_ 35.0
$node(3) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(3) 20

set node(4) [$ns node]
$node(4) random-motion 0
$node(4) set X_ 8.0
$node(4) set Y_ 50.0
$node(4) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(4) 20

set node(5) [$ns node]
$node(5) random-motion 0
$node(5) set X_ 65.0
$node(5) set Y_ 20.0
$node(5) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(5) 20

set node(6) [$ns node]
$node(6) random-motion 0
$node(6) set X_ 146.0
$node(6) set Y_ 5.0
$node(6) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(6) 20

set node(7) [$ns node]
$node(7) random-motion 0
$node(7) set X_ 20.0
$node(7) set Y_ 146.0
$node(7) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(7) 20

$ns node-config \
        -channel $chan_2_

set node(8) [$ns node]
$node(8) random-motion 0
$node(8) set X_ 70.0
$node(8) set Y_ 70.0
$node(8) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(8) 20

set node(9) [$ns node]
$node(9) random-motion 0
$node(9) set X_ 130.0
$node(9) set Y_ 180.0
$node(9) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(9) 20

set node(10) [$ns node]
$node(10) random-motion 0
$node(10) set X_ 160.0
$node(10) set Y_ 0.0
$node(10) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(10) 20

set node(11) [$ns node]
$node(11) random-motion 0
$node(11) set X_ 150.0
$node(11) set Y_ 165.0
$node(11) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(11) 20

set node(12) [$ns node]
$node(12) random-motion 0
$node(12) set X_ 110.0
$node(12) set Y_ 80.0
$node(12) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(12) 20

set node(13) [$ns node]
$node(13) random-motion 0
$node(13) set X_ 65.0
$node(13) set Y_ 114.0
$node(13) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(13) 20

set node(14) [$ns node]
$node(14) random-motion 0
$node(14) set X_ 50.0
$node(14) set Y_ 165.0
$node(14) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(14) 20

set node(15) [$ns node]
$node(15) random-motion 0
$node(15) set X_ 180.0
$node(15) set Y_ 100.0
$node(15) set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $node(15) 20 


###################################
#     Nodes placement
###################################
#parameters for trace Inspect
puts $scenarioTr "# nodes: $val(n), max time: $val(end)"
puts $scenarioTr "# nominal range: 250"
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n)} {incr i} { 
   set X [expr [$randomNodeX value] ]
   $node($i) set X_ $X
   set Y [expr [$randomNodeY value] ]
   $node($i) set Y_ $Y
   $node($i) set Z_ 0.0
   $ns initial_node_pos $node($i) 20
   puts $scenarioTr "\$node_($i) set X_ $X"
   puts $scenarioTr "\$node_($i) set Y_ $Y"
   puts $scenarioTr "\$node_($i) set Z_ 0.0"
}

###################################
# moving nodes
###################################
#$ns at 3.0 "$n1 setdest 62.0 55.0 25.0"
#$ns at 3.0 "$n7 setdest 52.0 12.0 5.0"

#############################
#    Data load
#############################
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n)} {incr i} {
    set udp($i) [new Agent/UDP]
    $ns attach-agent $node($i) $udp($i)
    set dest [expr round([$randomNode value])]
    while {$dest == $i} {
        set dest [expr round([$randomNode value])]
    }
    set monitor($dest) [new Agent/LossMonitor]
    $ns attach-agent $node($dest) $monitor($dest)
    $ns connect $udp($i) $monitor($dest)
    set cbr($i) [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
    $cbr($i) attach-agent $udp($i)
    $cbr($i) set packetSize_ 1000
    $cbr($i) set random_ false
    $cbr($i) set rate_ [expr $val(throughput) / [expr $val(n) * sqrt($val(n))]]Mb
    $ns at [expr $val(dataStart) + [$randomSeed value]] "$cbr($i) start"
    $ns at $val(dataStop) "$cbr($i) stop"
}

###################################
#    Nodes mobility (data load)
###################################
#for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n)} {incr i} {
#   set udp($i) [new Agent/UDP]
#   $ns attach-agent $n0 $udp($i) 
#   set dest [expr round([$randomNode value])]
#   while {$dest == $i} {               
#       set dest [expr round([$randomNode value])]
#   }
#   set monitor($dest) [new Agent/LossMonitor]
#   $ns attach-agent $n($dest) $monitor($dest)
#   $ns connect $udp1 $monitor($dest)       
#   set cbr($i) [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
#   $cbr($i) attach-agent $udp($i)
#   $cbr($i) set packetSize_ 1000
#   $cbr($i) set random_ false
#   $cbr($i) set rate_ [expr $val(throughput) / [expr $val(n) * sqrt($val(n))]]Mb
#   $ns at [expr $val(dataStart) + [$randomSeed value]] "$cbr($i) start"
#   $ns at $val(dataStop) "$cbr($i) stop"
#}

###############################
#   Routing model (for M-DART)
###############################
if {$val(rp) == "M-DART"} {
    Agent/ATR set macFailed_ $val(macFailed)
    Agent/ATR set etxMetric_ $val(etxMetric)
}

############################
#    Tracing
############################
;#Simulation time print
proc timeTrace { tracePause} {
    global ns
    set now [$ns now]
    $ns at [expr $now + $tracePause] "timeTrace $tracePause"
    puts "$now simulation seconds"
}

$ns at 10.0 "timeTrace 10.0"

if {$val(rp) == "MDART"} {
    for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n)} {incr i} {
        # printing the routing table
        $ns at [expr $val(end) - 1.0]  "[$node($i) agent 255] routingTablePrint"
        # printing the dht table
        $ns at [expr $val(end) - 0.5]  "[$node($i) agent 255] dhtTablePrint"
    }
}

#########################
#    Start and end
#########################
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(n) } {incr i} {
        $ns at $val(end) "$node($i) reset";
}

$ns at $val(end) "fileTrace"
$ns at $val(end) "$ns halt"

proc fileTrace {} {
    global ns tracefile namTr
    global ns tracefile scenarioTr
    $ns flush-trace
    close $tracefile ;#adding tis
    close $scenarioTr
    #close $namTr
    #exec nam nam.tr &
}

$ns run
```

This  script produce sent, receive and drop but no forward... The difference between this two script is at the **Data Load** part... Thanks :D

Comment: 2' file: `$ gawk -f all-2.awk ns.tr` replies `cbr s: 9514 r:4977 f:31512` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iTy8sBd6MD5UiR9gswJd7SRUienMhYYQ/view?usp=sharing  .... and .... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uuVmyH8QPe4SRz2g1dnpfCIMvP26pCDj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Or do this .... to count forward : `grep '^s' ns.tr | wc -l` ..... The count is 31512 from a 20.2 MB ns.tr